# using System.Windows; is not a name space

Tags: c#, wpf, syntax-error

I guess its a pretty basic mistake at which i should be ashamed off, but i just dont see it. I checked all the braces and they are correct. Im thankfull for any help.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace AmpelThingy
{
    public class Load       
    {

    void Loading() {
    StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(@"AA.xaml");
    string text = sR.ReadToEnd();
    sR.Close();

    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(text);
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);

    WrapPanel wp = (WrapPanel)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

    ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).SP2.Children.Clear(); // clear the existing children

    foreach (FrameworkElement child in wp.Children) // and for each child in the WrapPanel we just loaded (wp)
    {
        ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).SP2.Children.Add(CloneFrameworkElement(child)); // clone the child and add it to our existing wrap panel
    }           
}

/// <summary>
/// Clone a framework element by serializing and deserializing it
/// </summary>
/// <param name="originalElement"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
FrameworkElement CloneFrameworkElement(FrameworkElement originalElement)
{
    string elementString = XamlWriter.Save(originalElement);

    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(elementString);
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    FrameworkElement clonedElement = (FrameworkElement)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

    return clonedElement;
}
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have references to all the System.Windows libraries that you're using?

Comment: where are you getting error? which line??? Add some more text

Comment: sry wrong  text i edited it i get the error at every using statemant else then using system;

Comment: Did you create a WPF project? If not, you won't have the correct references, and you'll need to add them manually.

Comment: yes i did, is there a special class type i need to use when using a WPF project?

Comment: why shouldnt i have all references? Im using nearly the same as the MainWindow class uses and they all dont work. but how could i add maunal the reference?

Comment: Who the hell edited a comment into the question?

Comment: @aevitas me, cose i needet to add some text :P

Comment: Do i need to add the class in the xaml maybe?

Comment: @PaulBöttger - I have tried this in an empty WPF project (as simple class), it all works fine, except for `SP2` which is obviously part of your window class. What version of VS and what framework version are you targetting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have referenced `System.Windows`, `WindowsBase`, `System.Xaml`, `PresentationFramework` and `PresentationCore` in your project.

To add these, right click your project (not your solution), and go to Add -> Reference. Alternatively, you can expand the "References" item in your project to see which assemblies are referenced, and right clicking `References` to `Add` works too.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project references, you should see at least:

```
PresentationCore
PresentationFramework
WindowsBase
```

Which are needed for a WPF application.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a reference to assemblies listed here,

[Walkthrough: Manually Creating a Windows Presentation Foundation Project Using Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742193%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

- PresentationCore
- PresentationFramework
- WindowsBase

You many find the rest of the walkthrough of use too.

---

From here I deviate. Before inflicting WPF upon yourself, consider hosting your app in a browser.